How to change number of vertices (and other parameters) of primitives in blender 4.2
For some reason, in this particular project, each time I add a primitive the normal 'pop up' menus no longer appears. Is there a fix?


It's hard to tell without having your actual copy of blender, but if it helps your search, that "little pop up" is called the Operator Panel.

It's called Adjust Last Operation and you must have disabled it in View menu in the header of the 3d Viewport:

You could also just call it when needed from the Edit menu of the main window

or with  F9  if you prefer it disabled in the viewport or any other editor, even the ones that don't come with a View menu in their headers and happen to have operators with adjustable options:

